# Python での文字検索が意図した通り動かない

Tags: python

以下の問題に対して、自分が作成したコードではうまくいきません。
どこがいけないのでしょうか。

出典: coding_bat string2

> **問題:**
>
> Return the number of times that the string "code" appears anywhere in the given string, except we'll accept any letter for the 'd', so "cope" and "cooe" count.
>
> ```
> count_code('aaacodebbb') → 1
> count_code('codexxcode') → 2
> count_code('cozexxcope') → 2
> ```

**作成したコード:**

```
def count_code(str):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(str)-4):
    if str[i:i+2]=='co' and str[i+4]=='e':
      count+=1
  return count
```

Answer (score 1):

インデックスのオフセット値を間違えています。また、Python では `str` という名前はクラス名として使用されていますので別名にする方がよいでしょう。

```py
def count_code(text):
  count=0
  for i in range(len(text)-3):
    if text[i:i+2]=='co' and text[i+3]=='e':
      count+=1
  return count

if __name__ == '__main__':
  print(count_code('aaacodebbb'))
  print(count_code('codexxcode'))
  print(count_code('cozexxcope'))
```

Comment: ありがとうございます　改善できました

Comment: @kuratosu  この回答で問題が解決出来た場合、回答を承認してください。 [自分の質問に誰かが回答してくれたらどうしたらいいですか？ - ヘルプセンター - スタック・オーバーフロー](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)